# Migrating from spray to akka-http. respondWithMediaType

Tags: scala, spray, akka-http

I have quite a lot of API routes, and all of them uses this function to add headers:

```
 def jsonRoute(fn: => ToResponseMarshallable, method: Directive0 = get): Route = method {
    val jsonResponse = respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
      complete(fn)
    }

    if (corsAllowed) respondWithHeader(RawHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"))(jsonResponse)
    else jsonResponse
  }
```

Now I'm migrating from spray to akka-http, and respondWithMediaType is regarded as anti-pattern there. How to rewrite this function without changing it's interface?

Comment: I was migrating from spray also. And the solution which I found was to return the data as `JsValue`

Comment: add complete(response.mapTo[JsonObject])